# Communicating command line argument to another python

Tags: python, subprocess

So this is the scenario. I'm trying to program to run like `namefile.py (argument)` using this code:

```
process=subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,filename],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res=process.communicate(argument)
z=res[0].strip("\n").strip("\r")
```

Much of my supriseness, the program passes the `(argument)` not by the command line argument, but by standard output. What is the correct way?

Note: I want to **send** it, not receive it.

Comment: Where are you passing `(argument)`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply consult the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

The command-line arguments are passed to the `Popen` call, and have nothing to do with `stdin`/`stdout`.

```
import subprocess

args = ['/path/to/executable', 'first_arg', 'second_arg']
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

all_of_stdout = p.stdout.read()

exit_code = p.wait()
```

Comment: One tiny question. How do I receive standard output from the program I'm contacting? Is it like `p=subproces.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` `theOutput=p[0]` ?

Comment: p=subproces.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE) now output,error=p.communicate()...............use output or error whatever your program throws.

Comment: One more question. What should I do if the program that I try to connect is python? I tried `args=[[sys.executable,filename.py],argument]` but it return Windows 2 Error =0